# Not able to connect to USB modem on Ubuntu 14.04 using wvdial

Tags: usb, modem, wvdial

I am using wvdial to connect to my MTS Ultra Modem on Ubuntu 14.04
I get this output on *sudo wvdial mts*

```
Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

Here is my lsusb output :

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:0252 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 05ac:821d Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is my dmesg | tail output :

```
[ 2391.989570] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 2391.989670] usb-storage 3-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2391.989756] scsi9 : usb-storage 3-1:1.1
[ 2392.988527] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI:    2
[ 2392.988966] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2392.990894] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[ 2392.991035] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 2392.991416] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 2392.991841] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 2392.994204] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 0):

I slogged for days when i found it was this simple

First, run this command:

`sudo wvdial.conf`

This will set up the config file for you

Then run:

`sudo wvdial`

Shut down your wifi and run your browser and it will work,the problem is that the GUI for the network connections doesn't detect or is not able to connect to the modem but it is actually working.